# How to set manual key value in array instead of index in multi-dimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.0

I am using PHP 7.0 for my development. I got

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [lngCngSecUserId] => 0
            [sdtHolidayDate] => 1
        )

)
```

as output by following code:

```
<?php
    $tblActualHoliday = array();
    $arrColFields= array();
    $arrColFields["lngCngSecUserId"] = 0;
    $arrColFields["sdtHolidayDate"] = 1;
    array_push($tblActualHoliday,$arrColFields);
    print_r($tblActualHoliday);
?>
```

but I want output as

```
Array
(
    [ColHeader] => Array
        (
            [lngCngSecUserId] => 0
            [sdtHolidayDate] => 1
        )

)
```

How can I get it? I want ColHeader instead of 0 as index key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `"ColHeader"` as a key for entry in `$tblActualHoliday` the same way as `"lngCngSecUserId"` for `$arrColFields`.

```
    $arrColFields= array();
    $arrColFields["lngCngSecUserId"] = 0;
    $arrColFields["sdtHolidayDate"] = 1;

    $tblActualHoliday["ColHeader"] = $arrColFields;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$tblActualHoliday['ColHeader'] = $arrColFields;
```